# Changing view controller when Segmented Control changes

Tags: ios, storyboard

This problem is driving me crazy. I'm trying to change the `viewController` when the user changes the selected "tab" of the segmented control. I've spent a couple hours researching and haven't been able to find an answer that works or is done through storyboard.

It really bother me since setting a tab application is so easy, but trying to use the segmented control like the tab application is just not working. I already know how to detect which index is selected in the segmented control. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to swap out a _view_ or a _view controller_?  They're two different things.  If the latter, I'd suggest rolling everything into one view controller and show or hide subviews as they're needed.

Comment: Well I'm really new in iOS, the simplest thing that comes to my mind is change the viewController just like a tabbed application does. Do you suggest making various views and managing them with the same view controller? If so, How can I do that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it's much simpler to change subviews within a `UIViewController`, you can set up your subviews in your storyboards and hook them up with `IBOulets` in your controller you can set the `hidden` property of your views to YES or NO depending on the control that was clicked.

Now, if you use @Robotic Cat's approach which is also a good solution you can have a little more modularity in how your app works, considering you'd have to place all your logic in one controller using the solution I presented.

Comment: I like you suggestion just tried it out on xcode and looks good and easy to implement. My only concern is it inefficient to have views hidden in the background?

Comment: I haven't read anything in te developer docs that goes against this, though you have to consider that if you add a lot of visual elements it will take up memory, so do it wisely. To avoid this you could instiate everything you need on the fly, though I believe the overhead of having all the elements already set up is minimal. I only have 4 subviews each with 1 or 2 textfields for instance.

Comment: In one of my iPad apps, I have a view controller that has 7 subview that might be shown or hidden, each with its own set of controls. In all, there are about 60 views and subvies (labels, buttons, etc.). I don't notice any slowness or hesitation, and Profier doesn't reveal any huge spikes in memory or CPU. Obviously, you should test your own solution thoroughly, but I doubt you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 42):

**NOTE: Answer updated with view controller containment code for iOS 5+ including @interface section**

In an app of mine, I have a view controller with a Segment Control in the Navigation Bar and clicking on the "tabs" switches view controllers.  The basic idea is to have an array of view controllers and switch between them using the Segment Index (and the indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl IBAction.

Example code (iOS 5 or later) from my app (this is for 2 view controllers but it's trivially extended to multiple view controllers); the code is slightly longer than for iOS 4 but will keep the object graph intact.  Also, it uses ARC:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
// Segmented control to switch view controllers
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *switchViewControllers;

// Array of view controllers to switch between
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *allViewControllers;

// Currently selected view controller
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentViewController;
@end

@implementation UpdateScoreViewController
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the score view controller
    ViewControllerA *vcA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];

    // Create the penalty view controller
    ViewControllerB *vcB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];

    // Add A and B view controllers to the array
    self.allViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vcA, vcB, nil];

    // Ensure a view controller is loaded
    self.switchViewControllers.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:[self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.switchViewControllers.selectedSegmentIndex]];
}

#pragma mark - View controller switching and saving

- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*)oldVC toViewController:(UIViewController*)newVC {

    // Do nothing if we are attempting to swap to the same view controller
    if (newVC == oldVC) return;

    // Check the newVC is non-nil otherwise expect a crash: NSInvalidArgumentException
    if (newVC) {

        // Set the new view controller frame (in this case to be the size of the available screen bounds)
        // Calulate any other frame animations here (e.g. for the oldVC)
        newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));

        // Check the oldVC is non-nil otherwise expect a crash: NSInvalidArgumentException
        if (oldVC) {

            // Start both the view controller transitions
            [oldVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [self addChildViewController:newVC];

            // Swap the view controllers
            // No frame animations in this code but these would go in the animations block
            [self transitionFromViewController:oldVC
                              toViewController:newVC
                                      duration:0.25
                                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                                    animations:^{}
                                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                        // Finish both the view controller transitions
                                        [oldVC removeFromParentViewController];
                                        [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                        // Store a reference to the current controller
                                        self.currentViewController = newVC;
                                    }];

        } else {

            // Otherwise we are adding a view controller for the first time
            // Start the view controller transition
            [self addChildViewController:newVC];

            // Add the new view controller view to the ciew hierarchy
            [self.view addSubview:newVC.view];

            // End the view controller transition
            [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

            // Store a reference to the current controller
            self.currentViewController = newVC;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSUInteger index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (UISegmentedControlNoSegment != index) {
        UIViewController *incomingViewController = [self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:incomingViewController];
    }

}
@end
```

Original example (iOS 4 or before):

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the score view controller
    AddHandScoreViewController *score = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddHandScore"];

    // Create the penalty view controller
    AddHandPenaltyViewController *penalty = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddHandPenalty"];

    // Add Score and Penalty view controllers to the array
    self.allViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:score, penalty, nil];

    // Ensure the Score controller is loaded
    self.switchViewControllers.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self switchToController:[self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.switchViewControllers.selectedSegmentIndex]];
}

#pragma mark - View controller switching and saving

- (void)switchToController:(UIViewController *)newVC
{
    if (newVC) {
        // Do nothing if we are in the same controller
        if (newVC == self.currentViewController) return;

        // Remove the current controller if we are loaded and shown
        if([self.currentViewController isViewLoaded]) [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

        // Resize the new view controller
        newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));

        // Add the new controller
        [self.view addSubview:newVC.view];

        // Store a reference to the current controller
        self.currentViewController = newVC;
    }
}

- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSUInteger index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (UISegmentedControlNoSegment != index) {
        UIViewController *incomingViewController = [self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
        [self switchToController:incomingViewController];
    }

}
```

Comment: @Robotic Cat: I'm a bit confused why you set the frame of the child view controller to be the same as the parent view controller. Doesn't this parent view controller contain the UISegmentedControl? If so, wouldn't the child view controller obscure it?

Comment: @Marplesoft : Usually the `UISegmentedControl` is in the Navigation Bar.  Obviously, if your `UISegmentedControl` is in your view controller you should set your autolayout constraints or frame to the correct values for your app.

Comment: This is a great example. I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ADDRESS crash when I touch the segmented control (iOS 6, first example). It has the feel of something basic, like I constructed something incorrectly in the storyboard. Clues: 1) In the debugger, when I touch the control, I correctly have an oldVC and a newVC, but once the completion block runs there is no longer an oldVC. Is there a problem with the 'else' clause? 2) When the view first loads, the test label in the view isn't centered vertically (as it should be) - though the second view test label is correctly centered. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Thinking about that text layout difference, I turned off autolayout, and the segmented control correctly switches view controllers (Xcode 4.6.3). Consider this solved.

Answer (score 0):

UISegmentedControl is a little different in that it doesn't have a delegate protocol, you have to use the "add target" style. In your case what you want to do is add a target to be notified  when the UISegmentedControl changes (which is likely the parent view controller), and then that target can deal with the tab switching.

For example:

```
[self.mainSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changedSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In this example, the code is being invoked from some view/controller that has access to the variable for the segmented control. We add ourself to get the changedSegmentedControl: method invoked.

Then you would have another method like so:

```
- (void)changedSegmentedControl:(id)sender
{
   UISegmentedControl *ctl = sender;
   NSLog(@"Changed value of segmented control to %d", ctl.selectedSegmentIndex);
   // Code to change View Controller goes here
}
```

Note: this is untested code written from memory -- please consult the docs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this pod: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMailBoxContainer. It makes the UI animation among the view controllers. These view controller can extend UITableViewController or any other view controller.

I hope this help you!