# iOS Container ViewController data flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, protocols, uicontainerview

My objective is to show dealer locations in two different ways: a map and a tableview.

I have a container view controller (DealersViewController) which contains two child view controllers: DealersMapViewController and DealersListViewController. The user can switch between the VCs with a UISegmentedControl placed on the navigation bar. Tapping on a map annotation or a tableview cell will push a DealersDetailViewController.

The switching is already implemented (using code from [Changing view controller when Segmented Control changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422845/changing-view-controller-when-segmented-control-changes)) and seems to work fine, as does the pushing of the detail.

What I would like to improve is the flow of data between container and children. The dealer locations are downloaded (JSON) from the internet in the parent and on completion an NSArray *locations property is set on both the map VC and the list VC. This array will contain dictionary objects created automatically by AFNetworking, each with location data (each location dictionary will have a title, subtitle, latitude, longitude to conform to MKAnnotation protocol, but also other things like image and description etc).

My question is: How can I be sure that the container VC and both child VCs 'agree' on how location data is structured? Theoretically, if someone wanted to develop another child view controller to add to my container that shows dealer locations in a collection view for example, how can he formally know how to expect data.
Apple says: "If the container needs the child to declare methods or properties, it should define a protocol to enforce this:".  I could force the children to declare the locations property but the array could contain anything…

Maybe the parent could be a datasource for the children? I haven't tried this approach yet.

I am probably overcomplicating things but my objective is also to learn how to properly create reusable components and also practice using stuff like custom protocols / delegates and design patterns in general.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your issue is structuring data so that all of your controllers have the same understanding of it.

Probably the best way to go around it is to create a custom location class, and have the JSON deserialize into an instance of that class and then just pass it around as you see fit. There's quite a few ways how to go around deserializing, but [JSON Model](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) is a nice example of how to handle it automatically.

Tl;dr: convert your JSON dictionaries to custom classes and then pass them to your child view controllers, via properties or delegates, whichever you find more convenient.

Comment: The compliment Adis' answer, take a look at Objectify (http://tigerbears.com/objectify/). It'll help you create NSObject Models from your JSON data structures.

Comment: Thanks. If I were to use the delegate/datasource approach (which I'm starting to think could be appropriate) how would the children know the parent is ready to provide data? (that is, it has finished downloading the JSON)

Comment: If using protocols, simply make the children delegates of your parent view controller and create a method to be called when the data finishes downloading. Something in the lines of [self.mapDelegate updateLocation:myLocation];

Comment: But considering that the children are already contained in your parent view controller, a faster approach would simply be to make the update method public and then call it directly.