# ios uisegmentcontrol control switch between two views

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I"m attempting to create an app that has a UI Segment Control with two segments. Both segments will load a separate viewcontrollers while keeping the uisegmentcontrol still visible.

Doesn't any have a tutorial or sample code for the best practice to accomplish this task

Comment: Google for it. There are many popular segmented view controller containers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing view controller when Segmented Control changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422845/changing-view-controller-when-segmented-control-changes)

Comment: Note that in the question I've linked to the answers provide example code around view controller containment (which is what you want to use). But you can also do this with embed segues and simply hide the embedded view controllers you do not want to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create your own ViewController Container. We will just call this Container. Make Container, and add to it two views.  1) the segment control. 2) a blank view which will take the rest of the screen. We will call this blank view ContentView Container will have references to ViewController1 and ViewController2. When the segmented control value changes, get the corresponding viewController's view, and add it as a subview to your containers ContentView. when segment control changes again, remove the currently displayed view from the ContentView, and add the other ViewController's view to the Content