# iOS - Container View Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, containers

I am new to iOS development. On one of the app screens, I want to use segmented control with 2 segments - say A & B. A & B have different UIView. A has tableview, B has UIImageView and textLabels. I know that I need to use Container View Controller. But not sure how. If I am not mistaken there can be only one Embedded Segue to a View Controller - then how do I get 2 UIViews.

I don't know objective C so its difficult to translate answers from similar questions on SO to swift. Also don't want to go with view.hidden = false & true as I read its not good from a memory standpoint.

Can someone please explain step by step what needs to be done - how to use loadChildViewController, didMovetoParentController, etc. How will the storyboard look like.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be only one embed segue to one container. You'd have to create 2 containers with each one having it's own segue. Or you can add child controllers from code, just create `UIView` in which you want your content to be add child view controller and add child controllers' view to it. I created [sample project](https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/06-Containers) to show you storyboard setup as well.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

...

addChildViewController(controller)

containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view" : controller.view])
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view" : controller.view])
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)

controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: thanks for this..i saw the project its really helpful..one question: the setTranslates/ NSlayoutconstraint bit of code did not work for me..what are you trying to do..

Comment: If you don't do this the view is gonna try to change itself using auto resizing masks which doesn't go well with autolayout and causes autolayout crashes and/or unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Thant makes sense..but for some weird reason in the setTranslatesAutoResizing line -- there is an error "UIView does not have a member named "setTranslates..."...not sure what the error there is..Also..in the next line (var constraints)..there is an error for "H:|[view]|" saying that String is not convertible to "StringLiteralConvertible"

Comment: I guess you're using swift 2.0 then. `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is replaced with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property and `constraintsWithVisualFormat` no longer allows optional in options parameter, people usually pass something like this `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)` (but you can use something that makes sense like `AlignAllLeft`...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a container view why not just setup both views in the IB and then set the hidden property of a view based on the segmented control value.

Refer to this question for a more in-depth explanation.
[Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422845/changing-view-controller-when-segmented-control-changes)

Comment: don't want to use hidden views as those views are loaded but just hidden from the user. This takes up memory and is not ideal