# How to add an existing tableview controller into a viewcontroller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, twitter

I'm trying to show a twitter timeline in my app. I'm using Fabric, it's easy to setup, but it's using storyboard and tableview controller. I successfully show the timeline in a tableview controller, but I want to show the timeline under Twitter tab, like in the figure:

[image]

This is my code

```
TwitterViewController * twitterVC = [[TwitterViewController alloc] init];
...
[self.view addSubview: twitterVC.view];
```

It doesn't work. I just want to show the twitter timeline under the twitter tab.

Comment: You can use `Embed View Controller` in Storyboard to do this. Alternatively, if you want to add a view controller inside another view controller programatically, you can use my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11422845/558933 .This question is about switching view controllers using a `UISegmentedControl` but the code to add a view controller is the same. You will still need to use Autolayout to position the new view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try your answer first and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks @Robotic Cat, your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be going wrong here, but it's impossible to tell without more context in your question.

Firstly, I'd urge you to read [this article on View Controller Containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/).

Another thing that could be the issue here is the layout of the view; are you setting the frame of the Twitter VC manually? Are you using AutoLayout to set constraints?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I'm not familiar with the ios programming. The Twitter VC is just a tableview controller I drag to the storyboard, I did nothing with that. I want to add this tableview controller (or view) to my another view controller. I usually do this like [self.view addSubview: twitterVC.view], but this time, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as a childViewController.

```
    self.TwitterViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwitterViewController"];
    [self addChildViewController:self.TwitterViewController];
    [self.TwitterViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.TwitterViewController.view];
    [self.TwitterViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```